# In R program 'Select' query on dataframe is throwing error

Tags: r, data-science

When I am using the underline query over the data.frame `df_basket11`:

```
df_basket11$rules$lhs <- as.list(df_basket11$rules$lhs)
df_basket11$rules$rhs <- as.list(df_basket11$rules$rhs)
df<-sqldf("select [df_basket11$rules$rhs] from df_basket11")
```

It's throwing error:

> ```
> Error in vapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, FUN.VALUE = character(1L), ..., USE.NAMES = USE.NAMES) :values must be length 1,but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
> ```

Comment: `[df_basket11$rules$rhs]` is not valid SQL statment. If `rhs` is a column in `df_basket11` then you can run `df<-sqldf("select rhs from df_basket11")`

Comment: @A.Suliman Thank you, but after adding the code: df_basket11 <- transform(df_basket11, rules = colsplit(rules, pattern = "=>", names = c("lhs","rhs"))) I can find from View(df_basket) that the column name is "rules.lhs" and "rules.rhs". Applying your code gives me same error as before.

Comment: I think rules.lhs and rules.rhs are not valid columns names due to the dot. Try to change their names or put the name inside backticks as follows \`rules.lhs\`.

Comment: @A.Suliman -- df111<-sqldf("select 'rules.rhs' from df_basket11") is throwing error. The 'rules.rhs' column has been the default name assigned by the system. Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbiDataType’ for signature ‘"array"’

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer...we can do it by `$`(df_basket11 ,rules)  and then
  df_rhs<- sqldf("select rhs from df_basket12 where lhs like '%data_name%'")